# Getting all public static methods returns an empty list

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve all public static fields in a class using reflection. For some reason the List is empty although it shouldn't.
I am new to C# and came from java, so I probably misunderstood something. I hope someone can clarify this.

In my ReflectionUtils class:

```cs
    public static List<T> GetFieldValues<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                  .Where(f => f.FieldType is T)
                  .Select(f => (T) f.GetValue(null))
                  .ToList();
    }
```

In my MaterialType class:

```cs
public sealed class MaterialType
{

    public static readonly MaterialType GRASS = new MaterialType(1f);
    public static readonly MaterialType STONE = new MaterialType(1f);
    public static readonly MaterialType WATER = new MaterialType(1f);

    /* Just a constructor and a public readonly variable here */

    public static List<MaterialType> Values() {
        return ReflectionUtils.GetFieldValues<MaterialType>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f.FieldType is T` is true if the `FieldType` property of `f` **returns a value of type `T`**.

But `f` is `System.Reflection.FieldInfo`, and it hasn't ever heard of your `MaterialType` class. `f.FieldType` actually returns an object of type `System.Type` (they heard you like types). For the fields you care about, that `Type` object it returns is going to be equal to `typeof(MaterialType)`. If `T` is `MaterialType`, `typeof(T)` will be `typeof(MaterialType)` as well.

```
public static List<T> GetFieldValues<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
              .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(T))
              .Select(f => (T)f.GetValue(null))
              .ToList();
}
```

To use `is`, you'd want to get the value from the field you're looking at, and then check if the type of the *value* `is T`. But there's already an `OfType()` LINQ method for that, so we'll use it. As noted elsewhere, this may involve getting values we don't need, so the above solution is preferable.

```
public static List<T> GetStaticFieldValuesOfType<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
              .Select(f => f.GetValue(null))
              .OfType<T>()
              .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is the `is` operator:

```
f.FieldType is T
```

This is not what you intended, because `FieldType` is an instance of a `Type`(-derived) class *representing* the type of the field. It's not itself assignable to a variable of type `T`.

So you should use:

```
f.FieldType == typeof(T)
```

Comment: That did it. While I am at it I can though cast the values of the field to T like so `(T) value` and don't need a typeof there?

Comment: @Gerolmed `typeof` gives you the reflection type object that describes the type you use in the parentheses, so e.g. `typeof(string)` gives you the `Type` describing `string`. This has nothing to do with casting. `(T)obj` casts obj to type `T`, `typeof(T)` returns an object of type `Type` that describes the type `T`. You could use `f.GetValue(false) is T`, but that would require you to get value of *all* the fields, and return `false` for null values.

Comment: @Gerolmed yes, the _values_ are of type `T`, so you can cast them. Only `FieldType` is of type `Type` (or some derived) and cannot be cast to `T`.